# geo-stamping and geo-tagging in android

Tags: android, photo, geotagging

I have got a requirement to implement to Geo-stamping for images taken through Android device camera. I am wondering whether Geo-stamping and Geo-tagging both are same or different. How do i achieve Geo-stamping in android. Is that all i need to set latitude, longitude, altitude and directions for the image. Please provide me details and also any helpful links.

Comment: To add more clarity to it, I have taken a photo through camera. The details of the geo-tagging will be available in the picture if i have turned on my GPS where it is stored as a meta data. Now how do i send the meta data info along with this picture to server. I don't want to send the meta info in some parameters in the request URI. Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

i think they refer to the same term, in Geo Tagging you could add altitude, places name, accuracy of lat long etc also